# Resampling for each day timerange in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of holidays and for every holiday, I would like to downsample this to minutes. I want to merge it with another table that has minute data.

`holidays.head()` looks like:

```
day                         holiday
2012-02-20 00:00:00-05:00   1
2012-04-06 00:00:00-04:00   1
2012-05-28 00:00:00-04:00   1
2012-07-04 00:00:00-04:00   1
2012-09-03 00:00:00-04:00   1
```

Desired:

```
    day                         holiday
    2012-02-20 00:00:00-05:00   1
    2012-02-20 00:01:00-05:00   1
    2012-02-20 00:02:00-05:00   1
    2012-02-20 00:03:00-05:00   1
    2012-02-20 00:04:00-05:00   1
    2012-02-20 00:05:00-05:00   1
..
    2012-04-06 00:00:00-04:00   1
    2012-04-06 00:01:00-04:00   1
    2012-04-06 00:02:00-04:00   1
```

This:

```
holidays.resample('T').ffill()
```

is not sufficient as makes minute data in entire date range, not just on the holidays.

My attempt:

```
holidays.resample('D').apply(lambda x: x.resample('T').ffill())
```

does not work.

Anyone got a better idea?

Comment: What is the "-05:00" at the end of your `day` column? If your table contains only holidays, why can't you downsample and merge/mask on that table?

Comment: @Evan the "-05:00" is the timezone (see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html). By merging/masking on the next table, am I not just moving the problem to that new table?

Answer (score 0):

Two steps (df is your holiday dataframe)

```
v=df.day.str[-4].astype(int)+1  
df1=pd.DataFrame({'day':df.day.repeat(v),'holiday':df.holiday.repeat(v)})
df1.day=df1.day.str[:-4]+df1.groupby('day').cumcount().astype(str)+df1.day.str[-3:]
df1
Out[803]: 
                         day  holiday
0  2012-02-20 00:00:00-00:00        1
0  2012-02-20 00:00:00-01:00        1
0  2012-02-20 00:00:00-02:00        1
0  2012-02-20 00:00:00-03:00        1
0  2012-02-20 00:00:00-04:00        1
0  2012-02-20 00:00:00-05:00        1
1  2012-04-06 00:00:00-00:00        1
1  2012-04-06 00:00:00-01:00        1
1  2012-04-06 00:00:00-02:00        1
1  2012-04-06 00:00:00-03:00        1
1  2012-04-06 00:00:00-04:00        1
```

Comment: Thanks @Wen. I tried it, but for me it doesnt do what is intended. This duplicates the day. I changed it to `v=df.index.day`However, it doesn't add any minutes.

Comment: @MauriceKroon 2012-02-20 00:00:00-05:00 this is not the date format , then you can not use for date function with it